# Is it more fitting to say, "I left two comments on the page" or "I made two comments"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, american-english

Which is more appropriate "I left two comments on the page yesterday" or "I made two comments on the page yesterday"
Context: The page contains some changes to be reviewed by fellow teams made, and after reviewing the changes I made two comments to be addressed.

Not sure if using "I left" sounds good or not
I can't determine the intended meaning of "left" from the dictionary in this context.
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/left)
Could someone point out the meaning from the dictionary

Comment: OR *I **commented** twice on the page*. They're all fine. Use whichever you like best. But is "comments" the best way to describe your posts? Might they actually be more accurately called *questions*, if you want them to be "addressed"? You usually ***ask*** or ***raise*** questions, rather than ***make*** or ***leave*** them [somewhere].

Comment: @FumbleFingers On the page I'm referring to, clicking a line opens a text box with an "Add comment" button.

Comment: So what? Do you expect a separate box for "Add comment which is really a question"?

Comment: "Left" is the past tense of "leave". [Leave verb (1) sense 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave) has "leave a message" as an example.

Comment: Is "***teams made***" an autocorrect error for "***teammates***"? Either way, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and natural in your context, but it's probably worth understanding the difference between them.

To *leave something somewhere* suggests that it has some intended function in that place. "*I left two comments on the page yesterday*" suggests you put the comments there for somebody else to see, so this implies that someone --maybe the listener-- should read and address them.

In contrast, "*make a comment*" is a simple statement about something you did, and has no other implied meaning on its own. Maybe they're to help a teammate, or maybe you made the comments in anger, and expect nobody to read them or respond.

Your context is a project where people write comments for others to address, so it's clear that your intent is to have a teammate read and address the comments, so either of these sentences works just fine, and the "leave" version sounds a little more hopeful that they will be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

These are both fine and *"I left"* sounds natural in this context. This is the past tense of the verb *"to leave"* and this particular usage is a common phrase in English. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/leave-a-message

### Leave Behind

Leaving a message comes from the phrase "leave behind" which means to "go away from a place without taking someone or something."

For example:

> "I accidentally left behind my phone when I ran out of the scary movie! I'll have to go back and get it."

> "Could you please leave behind some of those paper plates? I'll need them later for the party."

> "She frequently leaves her shoes in the middle of the hallway."

### Leave a Message

When you leave a message, you interact with something and leave behind a message of some variety. This happens when you call and *leave* a voicemail or when you *leave* comments on something digitally or on paper.